# Extending a result in linear algebra to arbitrary rings

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and let $A$ be an $n\times n$  matrix with entries in $R$, $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ the adjugate matrix of $A$, and $I$ the $n\times n$ identity matrix. My goal is to extend the equation $\mathrm{adj}(A)A=\mathrm{det}(A)I$ (which is true if $R$ is a field) to an arbitrary ring $R$.

First we can show that $R$ is isomorphic to the quotient of a plynomial ring $S=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ (possibly infinitely many variables).

Second, in order to prove the equation for $R$, it suffices to prove it for $S$.

Third, in order to prove the equation for $S$, it suffices to prove it over its fraction field. Then, we can make use of the equation in field case and second step to finish the argument.

But I'm stuck on the second step. That is, in order to prove the equation for $R$, it suffices to prove it for $S$.

Any help/hint will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can prove it directly, for any commutative ring, using the properties of the determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical homomorphism $\pi:S\to R$ extends to a homomorphism $\bar\pi:M_n(S)\to M_n(R)$, $(s_{ij})\mapsto(\pi(s_{ij}))$. In particular, $\bar\pi(sI_n)=\pi(s)I_n$. If $s=\det A$, for $A\in M_n(S)$, we have $\pi(\det A)=\det\bar\pi(A)$. Similarly, $\bar\pi(\operatorname{adj}A)=\operatorname{adj}\bar\pi(A)$.